# Salesforce: Can AppExchange Apps Expose Customer Data to Web Services?

Tags: web-services, salesforce

Is it possible to create a simple Salesforce application that would allow other Salesforce customers to expose to install the app and expose their data to an **external** web service?

I know that it is possible to do this by having Salesforce customers add a 'Connected App' and a User account and then use the client_id and client_secret from the Connected App along with a username, password, and security token from a user account to authenticate a web service using OAuth. Unfortunately, this only works for more expensive accounts that have the ability to use the API and it is a little heavy. I was hoping for a workflow more like the following:

1. Customer installs my Salesforce app through AppExchange. The app tells them all of the permissions that it requires and they can make adjustments if they want.
2. My **external** web app is notified by my Salesforce app of the connection. It can now pull down data from the customer's Salesforce via the Salesforce API to do interesting things with it like create accounts for all of the users associated with the Salesforce account.
3. Now when someone wants to use my **external** web app, instead of using OAuth password grant_type, I can use OAuth token code grant_type to allow the user to access transformed Salesforce data that they should have permission to according to their Salesforce permissions.

Is this workflow possible or am I better off just limiting my app to customers that have more expensive Salesforce licenses and asking them to setup a Connected App and getting different client_id, client_secret, and user credentials for each customer?